# Extract first Member Of tuples in set in MDX

Tags: set, tuples, extract, mdx

I am new in Mdx queries and I have had a question about mdx, how can Extract first member of tuples in a set az a new set in mdx?
I have a query like this:

```
WITH
     SET [people in first date] AS   
   'Filter  
      (  
       {[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title]*[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/01]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/02]},
       [Measures].[Trade Cnt]>3
      ) ' 

       SET [people in second date] AS   
   'Filter  
      (  
       {[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title]*[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/03]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/04]},
       [Measures].[Trade Cnt]>0
      ) ' 

     /* SET [numberOfFirstItem] As
      [people in first date].item(0)*/

     member [measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate] AS
    DistinctCount([people in first date])

    member [measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate1] AS
    Count([people in first date])

     member [measures].[numberOfPeopleInSecondtDate] AS
     DistinctCount([people in second date])

     member [measures].[Ratio] AS 
     '(([measures].[numberOfPeopleInSecondtDate]-[measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate])/IIF([measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate]=0,1,[measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate]))*100'

 select
       [Measures].[Trade Cnt] on 0,
       [people in first date] on 1 
       --{[measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate],[measures].[numberOfPeopleInSecondtDate],[measures].[Ratio]} on 0 
      /* {[Measures].[Trade Cnt]} on 0,
       [people in first date] on 1*/
      -- {[numberOfFirstItem]} on 0

      from [DVPL]
```

I want to extract first member of `tuples` in first set - just `[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title]` because i want to distinct count name of `people` with mentioned query T have received Repetitious names.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get distinct count of all [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title] hierarchy members only. It's easier to not to use the tuple logic here at all. I'd create a measure to get distinct count of all members for the first date and distinct count for both the first date and the second date, plus their ration, apparently:

```
Member [Measures].[NumberOfPeopleInFirstDate] as
SUM(
    existing [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title].Members,
    IIF(
        Aggreagate(
            [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/01]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/02],
            [Measures].[Trade Cnt]
        ) > 3,
        1,
        NULL
    )
)


Member [Measures].[NumberOfPeopleInFirstDateAndSecondDate] as
SUM(
    existing [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer Title].[Customer Title].Members,
    IIF(
        AGGREGATE(
            [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/01]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/02],
            [Measures].[Trade Cnt]
        ) > 3
        and
        AGGREGATE(
            [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/03]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/04],
            [Measures].[Trade Cnt]
        ) > 0,
        1,
        NULL
    )
)

Member [Measures].[Ratio] as
[Measures].[NumberOfPeopleInFirstDateAndSecondDate] / [Measures].[NumberOfPeopleInFirstDate]
```